# Repetition code in C isn't working for large numbers

Tags: c

I'm writing a code in C to find the digits that repeat in a given number, and the one that I wrote works fine for small numbers, but the output gets messed up if I input a large value, N < 1000.
Here is my code; please help me out!

For the input:
1839138012980192380192381090981839

I get this output:
0 2 3 5 7 8

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int digit, digits[10], flag = 0, i;
    long long num;

    scanf("%lld", &num);

    while (num)
    {
        digit = num % 10;
        if (digits[digit])
            flag = 1;
        digits[digit]++;
        num /= 10;
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (digits[i] > 1)
                printf("%d ", i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
        printf("The are no repeated digits.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The output doesn't include some digits that repeat, and sometimes it includes the digits that aren't even there in the number.

Comment: How large before your program fails?

Comment: Show a specific number that does not work. Show the value of `LONG_MAX`(defined in `<limits.h>`)  in your C implementation.

Comment: If I include test cases of more than 100 digits or so, it fails

Comment: Do you mean one number of 100 or more digits, not 100 numbers?

Comment: Instead of scanning in `long int` (or even an `int`), just read in a string (`char *` or `char []`) and loop over each character in the string, to perform your test (see `atoi()`). You can then read in an integer that is much longer than `log10(LONG_MAX) + 1`.

Comment: Even if `long` is defined as a 64-bit integer on your system (which it may not be, and can be the same as `int` or 32-bits), then 100 digits is too big.

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your code? Either step through the code statement by statement in a debugger, while monitoring variables and their values; Or add lots of `printf` calls to print intermediate results and other info that might be useful to know.

Comment: The largest possible `long` is probably about 20 digits.

Comment: Thankfully, this code is easy to change to 'read in / loop a decimal _string_'. Consider if the task was to count the number of [duplicate] letters in input, instead of numbers.

Comment: How do I read in a decimal string?

Comment: A decimal string is _text_ that represents a decimal number. Like `char* ds = "123454321"`. Strings can be 'any number' of characters long. In a decimal string (or a string that _represents_ a decimal number), all the characters happen to be decimal digits, eg. 0..9.

Comment: The code works for small numbers so I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Re “For the input: 839819238190980 / I get this output: 0 1 3 8 9”: That is correct output. **Show a specific number that does not work.** This is not hard. You claim the program does not work for some cases. **Show a case.** Then people have a concrete example and do not have to guess. Most likely where you are going wrong is that `long` cannot hold large numbers. Instead of scanning the input with `scanf` to have digits converted to a `long`, you should just read the input character by character, check if each is a digit, and, if it is, count it.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I copied the wrong case. I updated it now, so please take a look at it.

Comment: 1839138012980192380192381090981839 is too big for `long`. It overflows, and a different value ends up in `num`. Stop using `scanf` to convert the input to a number.

Comment: So what can I use instead of scanf? I'm sorry, I'm kind of a beginner so I'm not well versed in this

Answer (score 2):

The `long long` type can only represent a limited range of numbers. In your C implementation, 1839138012980192380192381090981839 is too big for `long long`, and `scanf("%lld", &num)` does not work.

Instead, read each character of input using `c = getchar();`, where `c` is declared as an `int`. If, after `getchar`, `c` is `EOF`, stop looping and print the results. If `c` is not `EOF`, then check whether it is a digit using `if (isdigit((unsigned char) c))`. The `isdigit` function is defined in `<ctype.h>`, so include that header.

If the character is a digit, then convert it from a character to the number it represents using `c - '0'`. You can use `int d = c - '0';` to store the number in `d`. Then increment the count for the digit `d`.

If the character is not a digit, you can decide what to do:

- There will likely be a new-line character, `'\n'`, at the end of the line the user entered. You may want to ignore it. When you see the new-line, you could end the loop and print the results, you could continue reading to see if there are any other digits or characters before `EOF` is seen and report a problem to the user if there are, or you could ignore it and continue looping.
- There could be spaces in the input. You might want to ignore them, or you might want to report a problem to the user.
- If there are other characters, you might want to report a problem to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, which you could use with a string of some maximum length (defined by the constant `MAX_LEN`).

A string made up of a bunch of `char` will use one byte per character, so you can define `MAX_LEN` up to how many bytes you have in system memory, generally, although in practice you probably would use a much smaller and more reasonable number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 12345

int main()
{
  int digit, digits_checker[10] = {0}, flag = 0, i;
  char* num;

  /* set aside space for the string and its terminator */
  num = malloc(MAX_LEN + 1);

  /* read num from input */
  scanf("%s", num);

  /* get the string length */
  size_t num_length = strlen(num);

  /* walk over every character in num */
  for (size_t position = 0; position < num_length; position++)
    {
      /* 
         We assume that the value of num[position] is an 
         ASCII character, from '0' to '9'. (If you can't make
         that assumption, check the input and quit with an
         error, if a non-digit character is found.)

         If the input is valid, the digits 0-9 in the ASCII 
         table start at 48 ('0') and end at 57 ('9'). Subtracting 
         48, therefore, gives you the integer value at each digit 
         in num.
      */
      digit = num[position] - 48;
      /*
        Increment a counter for each digit
      */
      digits_checker[digit]++;
    }

  /* num is no longer needed, so we free its memory */
  free(num);
  
  /* check each digit */
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      if (digits_checker[i] > 1) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        flag = 1;
      }
    }
  if (!flag) {
    printf("The are no repeated digits.\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("\n");
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

The suggestion to check input is a good one. You can't necessarily assume that what someone enters will be entirely made up of digit characters.

But hopefully this demonstrates how to set aside space for a string, and how to read through it, one character at a time.